# Derivative of an Euclidean-Vector norm.

Tags: matrices, vectors, partial-derivative, image-processing

Consider:
**x** a $N \times 1$ vector , with elements $x_i$
**b** a $N \times 1$ vector , with elements $b_i$
**A** a $M \times N$ matrix , with elements $a_{ij}$  ( Symmetric matrix - Block Circulant )

As we know , the Euclidean-Vector norm of an equation $f={||Ax+b||}^2$ is:
 $${(Ax+b)}^T(Ax+b)$$  where $T$ indicates the Transposed form of a vector.

I have faced some difficulties studying about Image Restoration , with the Constrained Least Squares filter specifically , finding the proof that the first derivative of the above equation *$f$* with respect to ***x*** is:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\ {||Ax+b||}^2 = 2A^T (Ax+b) $$

I would be grateful if i could have some help!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you know how to differentiate a dot product $x. x$?

Comment: Well , i am pretty sure i know,yes . But my calculations do not lead to the equation above . I think i am missing a property of the derivation of the symmetric matrices , as i was searching the web.

But still , i cannot figure out the proof..

Comment: Use chain-rule and the fact that the derivative of $x \mapsto Ax$ is $A^T$, since $A(x + \Delta x) - A(x) -A\Delta x = 0 = o(\|\Delta\|)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. That post was helpfull enough!!
Now,my calculations led me to that answer above.

Comment: @P.Sidirp Can you post your calculation with details here. I will be thankful. I an not able to solve it.