# Chain rule for derivative of a norm

Tags: calculus, derivatives, normed-spaces, chain-rule

Suppose that $A$ is an $M \times N$ matrix, $x$ is an $N \times 1$ vector and $b$ is an $M \times1$ vector.

I want to compute $\frac{d}{dx}||Ax+b||^2_{2}$.

According to this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1651448/derivative-of-an-euclidean-vector-norm), the answer should be: $$2A^{T}(Ax+b)$$.

However, the chain rule gives me the transpose of this expression:

$$\frac{d\|Ax+b\|^2_{2}}{dAx+b}. \frac{d(Ax+b)}{dx}=2(Ax+b)^{T}A$$

Which answer is the correct one?

Comment: I think you are right. Are you able to prove it.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. My book omits this step given by Delta-u answer: $2((Ax+b)^TA)^T$

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct as these are the same.

The difference is the definition of the derivative. Let $f: E \to F$ a function.

If the definition of the derivative is:

$$f(x+h)=f(x)+\frac{df}{dx} \cdot h +o(\|h\|)$$

then your answer is the correct one.

But if the definition is:

$$f(x+h)=f(x) + \left( \frac{df}{dx} \right)^T \cdot h +o(\| h\|)$$ it is the one of the link.

---

In my opinion, the first one is the more natural and the most used. But the second one is closer to the case of function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ and can be very useful, however rather than derivative it is often called the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient).